# On Create collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor there is the `Accounts.onCreateUser` function that calls when a user is created.  Is is possible to do this on collections other than the User collection?

Answer (score 1):

I think not, since that method expect to returns a user object.

> The function should return the user document (either the one passed in
>   or a newly-created object) with whatever modifications are desired.
>   The returned document is inserted directly into the Meteor.users
>   collection.

I think the behavior from this method its special to the Meteor.users collection.

**Option**

if you want to have the same behavior from `Accounts.onCreateUser`  i recommend you to look at the [meteor-collections-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) package.

So you can do the following.

```
collection.after.insert(function(userId,doc){
 //do stuff here similar to Accounts.onCreateUser
 doc.subbmitedBy = userId; //for example
doc.createdAt = Date.now(); //from docs
});
```